# "View Parameter Info" feature not working in InteliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 Community Edition on Linux. Whenever I'm trying to bring up parameter info of a method while coding, nothing shows up. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, binding the shortcut to another combination and pressing that as well as navigating to `View > Parameter Info`, all of these options don't seem to do anything. For example:
When I try to view parameter info in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfNZp.png) snippet, nothing shows up.

The parameter info feature did work a few weeks ago and if I recall correctly, it was an update that broke the feature for me but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet where we can reproduce it? Please see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-277166

Comment: I don't know if this is what you were hoping for, but I edited the question.

Comment: Please, try out the [EAP version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/#section=mac) of IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: With the EAP version, everything works fine. Does this mean that I just have to wait until the new version releases and use the EAP version in the mean time?

Comment: Yes. As another workaround, you can enable JCEF on your 2021.2 version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-277166#focus=Comments-27-5156981.0-0